# Why blow-up for schemes actually "blow-up"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to figure out blowing up $\mathbb{A}^2$ along the origin in scheme theoretic way.
Let $R= k[x,y]$ be the coordinate ring, $I= (x, y)$ be the ideal corresponding the origin, and $S=\oplus I^n$. Then $X= \operatorname{Proj}S$ is the blow up as required.

My question:
How can I check $X$ is the same as the ordinary blow up that is $(x, y)\times (a:b)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1$ with the relation $xa= yb$ ?

Here's my approach.
Define a grade-preserved ring homomorphism
\begin{align*}
R[a, b]&\to S\to 0. \\
a&\mapsto x\\
b&\mapsto y
\end{align*}
Then this induces an isomorphism as graded rings
$$ R[a, b]/(ya- xb)\simeq S.$$
Therefore the blow up $X$ is covered by two basis $D(a)$ and $D(b)$.
On $D(b)$, let $t= a/ b$ and then
$$D(b)\simeq \operatorname{Spec}(R[a, b]/(ya- xb))_b^0= \operatorname{Spec}(R[t]/(yt- x)). $$
Then maximal ideals in $R[t]/(yt- x)$ should correspond to points $(x, y)\times (a: 1)$ in the ordinary blow up because this implies $X$ is exactly "blow up".
But I'm not sure how I describe maximal ideals.

Is this wrong? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Please use `\operatorname{Spec}` to produce $\operatorname{Spec}$ and likewise with Proj - I've made the upgrade for you this time. 2) It looks to me like you've pretty much already finished the problem - $\Bbb A^2\times\Bbb P^1$ is covered by two affine charts which have the exact same coordinate algebras as you've described here. Could you be more specific about what you don't quite believe yet?

Comment: Thank you for fixing the errors. It was not clear to me what maximal ideals of $T= R[t]/(yt- x)$ look like. For example, what is the corresponding ideal to $(x, y)\times (t: 1)= (2, 1)\times (2:1)$? But now I’ve found $(x- 2, y- 1, t- 2)$ is the maximal ideal because $T\simeq k[x, y, t]/(yt- x)$ (though this is not an isomorphism as graded rings), and we should consider maximal ideals of $k[x, y, z]/(yt- x)$ instead of those of $T$. Is it right?

Comment: I think it's correct. Here is another way how you might think about this: The surjection $R[a,b] \to S \to 0$ induces a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj} S \to \operatorname{Proj} R[a,b] = \mathbb A^2 \times \mathbb P^1$, which is exactly the "ordinary" blow-up of $\mathbb A^2$.

Comment: Thanks. That's another way of saying it's blow up.  I wondered why $\operatorname{Proj}R[a, b]= \mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$. So my question was not about blowing up for schemes, but just about ordinary blowing up.  I should fix the title.